# how do you execute a script a second time if the first execution does not succeed?

Tags: php

Here's this idea: A php script sends posted data to a different server. If the server fails to get the posted data, the php script should retry in a few minutes.

How do programmers get the script to be executed again in a few minutes to complete the task if the first try fails?

I want to create a php script that when being notified by a new update or insert by a database, makes a call to a different server and posts data to the server. So, no HTML/CSS/JS are involved. It's completely command line - running in the background. So, what if the first execution fails, how do I time the script to retry again in a few minutes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [at unix command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_%28Unix%29), so you don't need a script running while you're waiting for the right time.

```
echo "php yourscript.php" | at $TIME
```

You'd put this at the end of your php script, should the call to the other server fail.

```
shell_exec('echo "php yourscript.php" | at ' . $moment);
```

Comment: this is awesome... knew there was a way to do it without needing to create a cron job :)

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time if you need to schedule scripts with PHP you would have to rely on cron and then have some way to persist data relating to failure or success of the last script execution (i.e. DB or text file).

However if you have a script that you are running one time and you want it to try again periodically until it succeeds, you could use while loop with a timer like this:

```
// allow for long running execution
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);

$success = false;
while($success === false) {
    // attempt what you are trying to do, set $success to true if it works
    if ($success === true) {
        continue;
    } else {
        sleep(300); // this pauses execution for 300 seconds
    }
}
```

Edited per suggestion from Ross Smith II

Comment: You should add `ignore_user_abort(true); set_time_limit(0);` to that script

Answer (score 0):

You have stumbled on ajax friend.

For example:

```
var x = false;

function ajax()
{
 if(x)
 {
    $.ajax({
      url: "test.php"
    }).done(function() { 
      x = true;
    });
 }
 else
 {
    setTimeout(ajax(),3000);
 }
```

Comment: That's how you accomplish *each* execution, not how you get it to execute *again*.

Comment: not true. you can use javascript listner to return success bool.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear if this PHP script is run via a web server, or on the command line.

If you are talking about running on the command line, then do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
    php script_that_returns_non_zero_if_it_fails.php && break
    sleep 300 # sleep 5 minutes
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably create a function that calls itself after a `sleep()` if a condition returns false or equivalent.

```
<?php
function doSomething() {
    // do request, should return true or false
    $result = dymmyRequestFunction();
    if ($result === false) {
        sleep(300);
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: You should add `ignore_user_abort(true); set_time_limit(0);` to that script

Answer (score 0):

Ajax would be the answer.. something like this

```
xmlHttp.open('GET', '/ajax/script.php?id=' + id, true);
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
    {
       //complete
    }
    else
    {
       //try again
    }
}
```